# Jinja Flask Templating SQLAlchemy Displaying Multiple Results

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a simple search tool that searches an existing Postgres table, using Flask, Jinja & SQLAlchemy.
It's all working, except when I search, the result that is displayed on my page is like this:
[image: Flask Results]

Note the bit i've circled, is what would be displayed if I did the same search just using Postgres/pgadmin. It's returning multiple random results. 
Below is what would return by using Pgadmin:

[image]

Any ideas? My code is below.

> App.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import text
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='xxx://xxx:xxx@xxx:xxx/xxx'
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://xxx:xxx@xxxr:xxx/xxx')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db=SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def homepage():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        jn = request.form['jobnumber']
        rp = db.session.execute(text("SELECT cost FROM public.options where cast(optionno AS VARCHAR) like :jn"), {"jn": f"%{jn}%"})
        result_set = rp.fetchall()
        return render_template('main.html', result_set=result_set, jn=jn)
    else:
        return render_template('main.html')

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

> Main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>xxx</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
</head>

<body>
<p>xxx</p>

<form method="POST" id="jobnumber">
    <input name="jobnumber" type="text"  placeholder="jobnumber">
</form>

<table> 

<td>
<h1> Results</h1>
       <p>{{result_set}}</p>

</td>


</table>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I get it to only display the same as what PGAdmin would display?

Comment: If you want simple equality, don't use LIKE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be searching with `%`s in flask & without them in pgAdmin. If you need the same result in both, use the same query.

Enclosing the search string with `%` indicates to the SQL engine that you want to have values that contain your search string. Not just an exact match.

Comment: Thanks @fayaz i'll mark it as the answer when I'm able, my results are displaying ok now, but it's displaying [(2876.0,) how do I get it to only display the 2876 without the [( ,)

Comment: @keyring88 The resultset comes back to you as a [list](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) of [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). You can use the SQLAlchemy `.scalar()` method to strip those out because you already know that there's supposed to be only one result. To remove the decimal point, convert the result to an int, I guess.